# JAVA - saving excel (office 2010) without format warning

Tags: java, excel, warnings, office-2010, httpserver

I have to write some data in excel file. But when I'm opening excel file with this data, teher appears a warning:

```
`The file you are trying to open, 'name.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a thrusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?`
```

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010. 
And when I'm creating HttpServletResponse response I'm adding such information about header and content type:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", some info about file name + ".xls\"");
```

I have also tried to set another header like: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and file format as `.xlsx`, but it also doesn't help because the warning still appears.

When I'm trying to use .csv or .xml format, I don't have this problem, because no warning appears. Is there any possibility to programmatically get rid of this warning?

Comment: what is the content that you are pushing to the server?

Comment: I think I don't clearly understand your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: can you post the data (content) you are trying to write to xls?

Comment: I'm trying to do that on an empty document

Answer (score 0):

> The file you are trying to open, 'name.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension...

That is the standard Excel warning when loading an `xlsx` file with an `xls` extension. There is no way to avoid it programmatically. You will have to fix the underlying mismatch issue.

To debug:

1. Save a local copy of the file, change the extension to xlsx and see if it loads in Excel without a warning.
2. If it does then adjust your ContentType headers to suit.
3. If it doesn't then the file may be in some other format. Find out what that format is and again adjust the headers/filename to suit.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980395/10238) about [Extension Hardening](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx).

Comment: But should it be working good if I will set as ContentType as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet and xlsx extension? I'm creating this file for the first time, so I'm defining the extencion. I still can understand why the warning is appearing

Comment: The warning is appearing because there is a mismatch in the file format and the file extension. I think you need to answer the question that @Richie asked above: what is the format of the file that you generating on the server. Not the extension, the format. Or put another way: what library are you using to generate the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the comments above -  The error which you are getting is because content type which you are setting and the content does not match.Try posting an html with a TABLE with some data as content for  the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it got resolved after I changed to

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxml");
```